# Run flutter app on Android version 7.1.2 emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

How can I run my flutter app on **Android version 7.1.2** which has an **SDK version of 25**, because it does not exist on android studio.

Is there any other **emulator** to use? since I don't want to always to test on real devices and some of them are really hard to find.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download the sdk? Go to android studio settings and search for sdk and select what you need